# Is there a classical or nice way to apply different instructions to the first or last element of a loop?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa, loops, enumeration

Consider a loop. I am also interested by fast enumerations. So, it could be

- either a `for(id obj in objects)`
- or a `[objects enumerate... ]`

I want to know if there is a classical or nice way (in `Objective-C`) to make a distinction between the first element of the loop and the others. Of course, if there is only a nice way to distinguish the last elements from the others, I am also interested.

**Is there a classical or nice way to apply different instructions to the first or last element of a loop?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's easiest with a classic `for` loop but since you want fast enumeration you need your own counter:

```
NSUInteger index = 0;
NSUInteger count = objects.count;
for (id obj in objects) {
    if (index == 0) {
        // first
    } else if (index == count - 1) {
        // last
    } else {
        // all others
    }

    index++;
}
```

If `objects` is an `NSArray`, you can do:

```
[objects enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
    if (idx == 0) {
        // first
    } else if (idx == objects.count - 1) {
        // last
    } else {
        // all others
    }
}];
```

Comment: It's easier with NSArray's block methods, because they keep track of the index for you. I'd use those, personally.

Comment: You are assuming this is using `NSArray`. The OP doesn't state whether that is the case or not.

Comment: @rmaddy : With your code (for `NSArray`), is it a problem to call `objects.count` as many times as there are objects in `objects`? Do you in the compiler will optimize this?

Comment: You can store `objects.count` in a variable like I did in the first code block. Either way works. Using a variable instead of calling `count` every iteration is certainly more efficient.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what *nice* means, so here is my idea:

```
[array.firstObject doSomethingWithFirst]; // iOS 7 SDK or custom category

NSRange range = NSMakeRange(1, array.count - 2); //TODO: Check for short arrays.
for (id object in [array subarrayWithRange:range]) {
    [object doSomething];
}

[array.lastObject doSomethingWithLast];
```

It does what you want, you don't bother with counting indexes, uses fast enumeration, it's readable (first and last). The only weird thing on this is the `NSRange` part.

You may consider this *nice*.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the common statement of FOR you can do that:

```
for (int i = 0; i < [myArray count]; i++)
{
    if(i == 0)
        NSLog("First");

    if(i == [myArray count] - 1)
        NSLog("Last");

    //rest of your code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Even i would recommend to use these NSArray method :-

```
 - (void)enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:(void (^)
   (id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop))block
```

Comment: Also it will be faster to fetching the data

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind that enumerateObjectsUsingBlock does not guarantee about looping in ordered manner. A classic example for what you might be looking for:

```
const NSInteger sizeOfArray = 10;
NSInteger numbers[sizeOfArray] = {10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,100};

NSInteger i = 0;

do {
    switch (i) {
        case 0:
            NSLog(@"First");
            break;
        case sizeOfArray:
            NSLog(@"Last");
            break;
        default:
            NSLog(@"All others");
            break;
    }
    NSLog(@"Number = %i", numbers[i++]);
}while (i < sizeOfArray);
```

Comment: For ordered collections `enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:` will preserve ordering.